# USING ARROW KEYS TO SCROLL DOWN A DROPDOWN MENU

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu bar with dropdown menus when I mouse over the menu item [menu bar] the dropdown menu appears but I cannot use the arrow keys to scroll down the dropdown menu. If I click on the menu item I still cannot use the arrow keys to move down the menu. I presume it has something to do with focus [attribute]

> **CSS code:**

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-nav {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    color: white;
    background-color: #5F5F5F;
    font-size: 11.5px;
    top: 30px;
    scrollbar-base-color: #5F5F5F;
    height: 180px;
    overflow-x: no-display;
    overflow-y: no-display;
}

#menu {
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #5F5F5F;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 60px 0 0 0;
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    float: left;
}

.menu-size {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
    height: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

> **HTML Code:**

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="menu-size" href="#">home</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">works published</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#page3">best of the best</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#page9">recommended links</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#page9">books to research</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#page10">links to research</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you yelling at us?

Comment: Maybe his keyboard is broken and that's why the drop-down wont work with the arrow keys /s

Comment: I like that his name is also full caps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use bootstrap dropdowns? they come with lot of functions and can be easily customized with some other classes.

Take a look at the [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) examples of dropdown menus, they can actually do the navigation between items with the arrow keys

If you don't know how to add bootstrap to your website or project check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/)